# Every package "has no installation candidate"

Tags: ubuntu, apt, package-management

While attempting to install `openssh-server` on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit, I get the following error:

```
Package openssh-server is not available but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'openssh-server' has no installation candidate
```

I see the same error when trying to install any package.

This is the `sources.list` file:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hardy partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hardy partner
```

Comment: Have you run `apt-get update`? Also, have you checked if `sources.list` has the relevant entries?

Comment: Please post the output of `apt-cache policy`.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text output: post the text so that it can actually be read...

Comment: salman@salman-Inspiron:~$ sudo apt-cache policy
[sudo] password for salman: 
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
Pinned packages:
salman@salman-Inspiron:~$

Comment: @psimon If you're going to remove the image of the error, make sure you copy the relevant text back in. I'm not saying the original was great but you left this post in an unanswerable state.

Comment: @Oli No, I didn't remove the image. Please take a look at the revision history, my edit only improved the formatting. As I see, OP removed the image.

Comment: @psimon Ever-so-sorry, I read it wrong.

Comment: @Oli no problem. But salman, please include the error message in your question. Oli is right - this is unanswerable in this state.

Comment: I suggested an edit that should make this answerable, it just needs approving.

Answer (score 31):

If that's really the whole of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, that explains your current situation. And I've got no explanation for why you have a Hardy repo installed. I suspect you've followed an old tutorial and it has broken things.

Your first step is getting your repos back on track. I would suggest using a tool like [RepoGen](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) to get the basics in but failing that, here are the most essential:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Stick those in the right place with `sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list` (you might as well ditch those lines about hardy). When that's saved, run `sudo apt-get update` and then you should be able to install things again.

Comment: This answer helped with https://askubuntu.com/questions/789302/install-python-wxgtk2-8-on-ubuntu-16-04 for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem, I tried all the above solution along with checking over Ubuntu software center.I couldn't crack to solve it.I have tried another way which worked for me. Here is my solution

Firstly we need to be connected to the internet for update process to happen.

```
$sudo apt-get remove openssh-client

$sudo apt-get update
```

If the update cant happen because of `/var/lib/apt/lists/lock` you may remove that file, which will help to download the update process. Then run the following command which should work

```
$sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Comment: Don't try this, it didn't work for me and now I have less than before

Comment: Agree, don't try this. Removing `openssh-client` was successful and installing `openssh-server` (in my case) ended up with installation error. As a result I broke up everything...

Answer (score 3):

This error message indicates a 'virtual package' that exists only in the `Provides:` line of another package, or is referred to in the `Depends:`, `Recommends:` or `Suggests:` lines of other package(s).

To list the packages that have 'Provides: openssh-server', you'd run:

```
aptitude search "?provides(openssh-server)"
```

I suspect you have other problems on your ubuntu system, probably in your `sources.list` file(s) - on debian, at least, openssh-server is an actual package, not a virtual package.  I'd be surprised if it was any different on ubuntu.

```
$ aptitude search "?provides(openssh-server)"
i   openssh-server                  - secure shell (SSH) server, for secure acce
p   openssh-server:i386             - secure shell (SSH) server, for secure acce
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and removed and added the sources list over and over. In the end it turned out I had a foreign architecture *armhf* also installed and that caused problems. So first a purged all ARM packages and then the architecture.

```
apt-get purge ".*:<arch>"
dpkg --remove-architecture <arch>
```

After that `apt-get update` ran without issues and I could finally update packages again.