# Package libapr1-dev is not available

Tags: ubuntu, package-management

I'm trying to install libapr1 and libaprutil1 and the issues I'm facing are as follows:

```
Package libapr1-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
Package libaprutil1-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libapr1-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libaprutil1-dev' has no installation candidate
```

How do I get this to work and install the needed packages? I have tried using solutions offered in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140131/292514) and it did not resolve my issue.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @Zanna I'm using ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @SivaPrasath the solution offered by Oli did not help.

Comment: If existing solutions did not help, please mention exactly what you tried and why they did not help. Voting to close otherwise.

Comment: I have added the lines as suggested by Oli from the linked answer in my answer in the concerned file and then tried installing as `sudo apt-get install libapr1-dev libaprutil1-dev`. One of my friends also suggested me to do `sudo apt-get install httpd-devel` but yet again it says `E: Unable to locate package httpd-devel`

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show the output of `apt policy`?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you are trying to install a package about which APT does not have any idea. When you add software sources and then do an apt-get update your system APT's database is updated with all the packages on the repositories listed in software sources list.

Then when you try to install any package, apt checks the package name in its database finds it and checks the name of the repo from where it got it. It then downloads the package from that repo.

This means of all the repositories listed in your software sources, none of them have the package named `libapr1-dev` and `libaprutil1-dev`

After a bit of googling, I found that it is package is available with `apache2` PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
```

Add the PPA  and try...

Let me know if it works.

Comment: hey, after adding the PPA I'm still seeing the same problem of "package missing, obsolete or available from other source"

Comment: have you did `apt-get update`

Comment: I did do an update